# SonarQube 5.2 Issue Density plugin deprecated, alternatives?

Tags: sonarqube

The Issue Density plugin is deprecated in SonarQube 5.2. We primary use this plugin in the Widget Lab Plugin.

Checking the upcoming [release 5.3 (2016-01-08)](https://jira.sonarsource.com/projects/SONAR/versions/11647) and release 5.4 (2016-03-04) I see no mention of this being fixed in either release. Looking a bit further I even see that the plugin will [never be made compatible with any SonarQube version 5.2+](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-81).

Are there any alternatives to this plugin?

Comment: We used it to be able to retrieve the metric 'violations_density' from the Web Service API which we use to visualize project trends. We can still retrieve old values (after upgrading from 4.5.x LTS) but there are no new values stored for this metric.